# Output of printf out of order

Tags: c, function, printf

I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void ExecAsRoot (char* str);
int main ()
{
  printf ("Host real ip is:");
  ExecAsRoot("ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/'");
  return 0;
 }

void ExecAsRoot (char* str) {
  system (str);
}
```

My expected output is:

```
Host real ip is:7.17.11.29
```

While the actual output is:

```
7.17.11.29
Host real ip is:
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The output of `printf` is being buffered because the string being printed does not contain a newline.  As a result, the buffer does not get flushed until the  program ends, and therefore appears after the output of the `system` command.

To flush the buffer, use `fflush`:

```
printf ("Host real ip is:");
fflush(stdout);
ExecAsRoot("ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/'");
```

If you want all writes to `stdout` to be unbuffered, you can use `setvbuf` to disable buffering:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);     // _IONBF = unbuffered
```

Or more simply:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Then all writes to `stdout` will appear immediately.

Comment: Is there a way to implicitly "declare" that I need fflush on every printf? Other than wrapping it in a function which contains fflush?

Comment: @Droidzone You can't have executable statements, such as a function call, outside of a function.  You need to put the call to `setbuf` in a function, preferably at the start of `main`.

Comment: Worked with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`

Comment: @Droidzone Right!  Edited.

Comment: @Droidzone note that it disables buffering, not that it'll call `fflush` on every `printf`

Comment: use   printf ("Host real ip is:\n"); to avoid this misbehavior

Comment: @EsmaeelE Obviously if I do that IP gets printed on another line, which wasnt what I wanted.

Comment: @Droidzone  Thanks for good  question that i learn some weird thing on C. fflush() the output solve it. I know what is the problem but i cant find out what is the application of it.